# TCPDF ignores inline font-weight and font-style in $pdf->ImageSVG() when having single font file

Tags: tcpdf

I have the following svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="450" viewBox="0 0 600 450" xml:space="preserve">
  <g transform="translate(300 77)">
    <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Slabo-Regular" font-size="40" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;"><tspan x="-44.44" y="12.57">Slabo</tspan></text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(300 230)">
    <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Slabo-Regular" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;"><tspan x="-44.44" y="12.57">Slabo</tspan></text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(300 389)">
    <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Slabo-Regular" font-size="40" font-style="italic" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;"><tspan x="-44.44" y="12.57">Slabo</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Which has a 1st line written in regular "Slabo", the 2nd line has a font-weight "bold", and the 3rd line has a font-style "italic".

However, when i convert this svg to pdf using TCPDF method named ImageSVG() i get all the lines written in regular "Slabo". This a test case for a font with a single file (i know how to do this if i had different files for each font variation).

It seems that TCPDF ignores the inline font-weight and font-style.

Is this the expected behavior or i have done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, TCPDF will not approximate font bolding or italic styling. That is, it won't try to approximate a font style/weight it doesn't have on the fly like your browser would.

If you don't want to modify your SVG(s) or rasterize them with ImageMagick you have two options that I'm aware of:

**1) Provide other fonts as fills for the Slabo styles you don't have**

This option is probably easiest. Since Slabo only has a regular weight/style available, you can pick decently similar stand-in fonts, and then rename their files so they'll match TCPDF's naming rules for Slabo's other styles.

```
$slabo = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath('./slabo/Slabo-Regular.ttf'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
//Regular
$slaboi = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath('Slabo-Italic.ttf'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32); 
//Italic
$slabob = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath('Slabo-bold.ttf'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32); 
//Bold
$slabobi = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath('slabobi.ttf'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32); 
//Bold and Italic (file could have also been named something like Slabo-Bold-Italic.ttf)
```

TCPDF will then find these other fonts when the SVG parser handles the text elements. (*For the bold example:* Internally, Slabo-Regular will be changed to slabo, and then because you want bold, it'll look for slabob, which exists and then that font will be used.)

Below is an example with stand-in fonts. (Not carefully selected.)

[image: Slabo replacement example]

**2) Generate approximated bold/italic styles.**

You could create your own Slabo styles. For example, with a tool like *FontForge*

http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Bold_and_Other_Weights.html

> Creating a bold version of a font can be rapidly approximated by
>   running a filter called Change weight (which you will find in the
>   Element > Styles menu) to add weight to your glyphs.